# KeyError: 'id' in django rest framework when trying to use update_or_create() method

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, postman, put

I am trying to update the OrderItem model using update_or_create() method. OrderItem model is related to the Order model with many to one relationship ie with a Foreignkey.

I am trying to query the orderitem object using id and update the related fields using default as you can see, but got this error.

My models:

```
class Order(models.Model):    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)   
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    total_price = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    #billing_details = models.OneToOneField('BillingDetails',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,related_name="order")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Orders"
        ordering = ('-id',)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    #user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True,related_name='order_items')
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    order_variants = models.ForeignKey(Variants,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)    
    ORDER_STATUS = (
        ('To_Ship', 'To Ship',),
        ('Shipped', 'Shipped',),
        ('Delivered', 'Delivered',),
        ('Cancelled', 'Cancelled',),
    )
    order_item_status = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=ORDER_STATUS,default='To_Ship')
```

My view:

```
class UpdateOrderView(UpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderUpdateSerializer
```

My serializers:

```
class OrderUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    order_items = OrderItemUpdateSerializer(many=True)
    billing_details = BillingDetailsSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['id','ordered','order_status','order_items','billing_details']


    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.order_status = validated_data.get('order_status')
        instance.ordered = validated_data.get('ordered')

        #billing_details_logic

        billing_details_data = validated_data.pop('billing_details',None)
        if billing_details_data is not None:
            instance.billing_details.address = billing_details_data['address']
            instance.billing_details.save()


        #order_items_logic
        instance.save()

        order_items_data = validated_data.pop('order_items')
        # print(order_items_data)
        #instance.order_items.clear()
        for order_items_data in order_items_data:
            oi, created = OrderItem.objects.update_or_create(
                id= order_items_data['id'],
                defaults={

                    'quantity' : order_items_data['quantity'],
                    'order_item_status': order_items_data['order_item_status']

                }
            )
            
        super().update(instance,validated_data)
        return oi
```

Updated serializer:

```
for order_item_data in order_items_data:
            oi, created = instance.order_items.update_or_create(
                id= order_item_data['id'],
                defaults={

                    'quantity' : order_item_data['quantity'],
                    'order_item_status': order_item_data['order_item_status']

                }
            )
```

The order_items data are sent like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`order_items_data` is a `list`.
Then you iterate over it with the same variable name.

```
        for order_items_data in order_items_data:
```

Just rename it to something like

```
    for order_data in order_items_data:
```

and there will be an `id` in your `order_data`.

Comment: Yes, I remaed it to order_item_data, but got the same error. Any idea?? @Tom

Comment: Just added. You can have a look at it.

Comment: Are you sure `order_items_data` is a list of dicts and not list of `OrderItem`? If so, you'd have to access `id` by `order_item_data.id`, not `order_item_data['id']`.

Comment: Yes, its a list of dictionaries, because one order can have many order_items. In the postman, I am sending data like this. "order_items": [ {},{},{}...]. But right now, Iam only sending only one {}.

Comment: Yes but in `validated_data` it's already mapped to the ORM, I think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230497/discussion-between-saroj-paudel-and-tom-wojcik).

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't getting the id on the `OrderedDict` also, so I've added a `id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)` on the serializer and put that `id` into the `update_or_create` method:

```
  for obj in data:
      Model.objects.update_or_create(
          pk=obj.get('id', None), ...
      )
```